# set button condition based on other button condition

Tags: java, user-interface

currently my program have a selection page which contain 4 action button with one terminate button and after the user click into one of the action button the button will set enabled (false) and i want to set terminate button in false mode when those 4 buttons are enabled but when 4 button is diabled than the terminate button will be enabled

```
do {
    if (SIG.isEnabled() && RG.isEnabled() && AaCG.isEnabled() && SRG.isEnabled()) {
        Terminate.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        Terminate.setEnabled(true);
    }
} while (Terminate.equals(false));
}
```

try to use do while loop but i dont know how to code it properly

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ActionListener` to the button. The code it contains will be executed everytime the button is pressed.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // Do your check here
        if (SIG.isEnabled() && RG.isEnabled() && AaCG.isEnabled() && SRG.isEnabled()){
            Terminate.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            Terminate.setEnabled(true);
        }       
    }
});
```

PD: According to the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), your variable, fields and method names should start with a lowercase letter, to not confuse them with a Class or an Interface.

Comment: If this answer has worked for you (or any other answer in any other of your questions), please [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) so people can see which answer solved the problem.